# How to explicitly set sagemaker autopilot's validation set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, automl

The example notebook: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/autopilot/autopilot_customer_churn.ipynb states that in the Analyzing Data step:

`The dataset is analyzed and Autopilot comes up with a list of ML pipelines that should be tried out on the dataset. The dataset is also split into train and validation sets.`

Presumably, autopilot uses this validation set to select the best performing model candidates to return to the user. However, I have not found a way to manually set this validation set used by sagemaker autopilot.

For example, google automl, allows users to add TRAIN, VALIDATE,TEST keywords to a data_split column to manually set which data points are in which set.

Is something like this currently possible which sagemaker autopilot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do this at the moment. The validation set is indeed built by Autopilot itself.